# How to display dynamic content into ck editor using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
ck editor text area
<textarea cols="100" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="50" data-ng-model="report.reportlist">

</textarea>
<div>{{ report.reportlist }}</div>
```

I am getting value inside div but not in ck editor

My controller

```
$scope.report.reportlist = data ;

data = <p><h1>PRO/AH/EDR> African swine fever - Belarus (03): (HR) 1st rep, OIE, RFI</h1><br/><br/><p>African Swine Fever &mdash; Worldwide/Unknown<br/></p>
```

I am not getting why it is not showing in CK editor .
I am using angular js

Comment: Can i ask why *"African swine fever - Belarus"* ?

Comment: That is the data i am getting from service , i got the issue now ,i have to reload the editior each and every time once response change ,but how i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the content inside the CKEditor isn't actually in the textarea itself (the textarea element gets hidden). To keep your scope variable and CKeditor in sync you will need to listen for the CKEditor events and update your scope variable accordingly.
I made a quick demo here: http://jsbin.com/iMoQuPe/2/edit

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="CkCtrl">
    <textarea name="editor" id="" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="editorData"></textarea>
    <pre>
      {{ editorData }}
    </pre>
  </div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function CkCtrl($scope) {
  // Load initial data, doesn't matter where this comes from. Could be a service
  $scope.editorData = '<h1>This is the initial data.</h1>';

  var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

  // When data changes inside the CKEditor instance, update the scope variable
  editor.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
    this.document.on("keyup", function () {
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.editorData = editor.getData();
      });
    });
  });
}
```